# Python Pandas indexing provides empty DataFrame error

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu

I am new to Python and trying to indexing and slicing of my data using Pandas in Python but it gives me an error of "Empty DataFrame".
Following are my python lines:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df = pd.read_csv(filename,delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=['year','month','lat','lon','aod','toa','sfc'])
df.set_index('year','month','lat','lon','aod','toa','sfc', inplace=True, drop=True)
idx = pd.IndexSlice

tmp = df.loc[idx[2011,3,10.0,30.0,:,:,:],]
print(tmp)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(2011, 3, 10.0, 30.0, 1.031, 228.524, 987.44), (2011, 3, 10.0, 30.0, 0.28300000000000003, 202.205, 1036.77), (2011, 3, 10.0, 30.0, 0.45899999999999996, 214.261, 1054.85), (2011, 3, 10.0, 30.0, 0.35100000000000003, 201.296, 1064.03), (2011, 3, 10.0, 30.0, 0.15, 195.709, 1073.97), (2011, 3, 10.0, 30.0, 0.204, 201.37599999999998, 1061.8), (2011, 3, 10.0, 30.0, 0.39899999999999997, 195.92700000000002, 1041.49), (2011, 3, 10.0, 30.0, 0.612, 203.899, 1018.99)]
```

These lines give me the results without slicing with Empty Dataframe error.
I will grateful if someone points out the solution.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: I edited your questions as 1) the standard abbreviation for `pandas` is `pd` 2) there is no point to define a function in this context,

Comment: Try to use iloc[] and add a colon(:) after the comma.

    tmp = df.iloc[idx[2011,3,10.0,30.0,:,:,:], : ]